# Soap Address Location : ServiceStack SOAP 1.2

Tags: soap, wsdl, servicestack

I've been looking around for an answer but I've found nothing that solves my problem, forgive me if this has been asked before.

I've got a REST and SOAP API and my problem is that when i add my swdl into  SoapUI it opens it up and points to the wrong protocol.  It gives me: "http://".  I think this is to do with this line:

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost/servicestack/api/soap12"/>
```

Does anyone know how I can change the soap address location to "https" in servicestack?

From what I've read so far it's to do with the url that you come from, but I've come from a https protocol and it still gives me http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the dynamically generated WSDL in ServiceStack by overriding `AppHost.GenerateWsdl()`, e.g:

```
public override string GenerateWsdl(WsdlTemplateBase wsdlTemplate)
{
    var wsdl = base.GenerateWsdl(wsdlTemplate);
    return wsdl.Replace(
        "<soap:address location=\"http:",
        "<soap:address location=\"https:");
}
```

### [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference)

Also as an alternative to SOAP you can use [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference) which like SOAP allows generation of a strong-typed API from a remote url, integrates with most major IDE's and holds a number of [advantages over WCF/SOAP](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference#advantages-over-wcf).

Comment: Thanks Mythz.  I noticed I was able to fix the problem by changing my IIS settings (doh).  The above also works and will save me some time writing deployment code for the time being.  Cheers.